# How would you integrate this $\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac {\{x\}\cos (ax)}{x^b}\mathrm {d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac {\{x\}\cos (ax)}{x^b}\mathrm {d}x$$
here $\{x\}$ represents the fractional part and can be denoted by 
$$\{x\}=x- \lfloor x \rfloor $$

Comment: Quite interesting question. Just a small comment: it seems Mathematica cannot do this integral analytically, but it gives a number when numerically integrating so it's possible in theory. Sorry for not being able to help more...

Comment: $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac {\{x\}\cos (ax)}{x^b}\mathrm {d}x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int^{k+1}_{k} \dfrac {\{x\}\cos (ax)}{x^b}\mathrm {d}x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int^{k+1}_{k} \dfrac {(x-k)\cos (ax)}{x^b}\mathrm {d}x$$

The reset depend on the values of $b$.

Comment: so for what values of $b$ is it integrable ? @ZaidAlyafeai

Comment: It's always integrable on each interval $[k, k+1]$, but I guess your question is when you can exactly calculate the integral by hand. My intuition is this should be possible when $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ but I have yet to work this out.

Comment: The function is integrable for $b > 2$